# Catfish authentication failed

Tags: operating-systems, kali-linux

my file system was working fine, I don't know what happened it doesn't show my directories, this is because of `catfish` I have to update it, but when I update it appears:

[image]

Error: **Authentication failed**

I want to know how I can update and be back to normal, I wanted something like this, just like before:

[image: image2]

Currently my file system looks like this:

[image]

**Obs: I'm using Kali Nethunter. And I'm already logged in as root**